# circularness of imputing draws via regression in MCAR

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, simulation, missing-data

Suppose we have covariates $X$ and outcome $Y$. Part of $X$ is missing under MCAR. I am reading Rubin's Missing Data book. I do not see why the following statement making sense intuitively. Let $x,y$ be completely observed covariates and outcomes.

"However, our recommended approach is to impute draws (not means) from the conditional distribution of the missing covariates given the observed covariates and Y; this approach yields consistent estimates of the regression coefficients and hence is not circular"

The book is basically asking to draw missing covariate $\mathcal{X}$ from $P(\mathcal{X}|y,x)$. If we are doing regression $\mathcal{X}$ on $y,x$ first and draw randomly from previous distribution for $\mathcal{X}$. Then we use filled data $\tilde{X}$ by filling missing entries by $\mathcal{X}$ to predict $Y$. Should not this yield bias toward regression of $Y$ on $Y$ regression and covariates having very small role to play?(For regression of $Y$ on $\tilde{X}$, the completely observed data will not be affected.) I find this very counter intuitive to conclude there is no bias in estimation of regression coefficients.